# how to keep the local database file that will not be corrupted ?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application that i wrote using sqlite for data persistence.
I decide to create local db file and to this file i read/write my data.

Because there is an option that the user will do something ( like turn off his device ) that will corrupt this db file - i want to create backup db file that will be override at the end of the writing process to the db file.

( i will always hold 2 db files .. one is the not last update that differently not corrupted and one is 'dirty' db file that hold the latest data - and my app will write to this file and make the swap between those two files after writing )

1. Is there some other way to avoid a case of corrupted db file ?
2. Is there some code example or some lib of how to do this backup on android code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to avoid the risk of a local SQLite database getting corrupted would be to mirror your critical data to the server, ultimately to a more permanent database which is more stable.  So as an example here you could periodically sync your local user data with the server.  If you detect corrupt data, of if things are so bad that you can't read at all, you would not update with that data, and you might even use the server side database data for doing a restore of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check out [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) - a new library which is an abstraction layer over SQLite that comes to deal with issues programmers face when managing SQLite database manually. Personally, I've migrated to Room and it solved for me some issues (other than yours, but still) that I was struggling with before.